# How to add a delete button to Collection View Cell in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Right now I have a list of scrolling usernames using a Collection View of buttons. But I’d like to add overlapping delete buttons to each row. They'd need to be attached to the name buttons and scroll with them.

How can I add these buttons to my CollectionView?
(Also I'd like to skip the delete button on the first row for obvious reasons)

[image: User Selection Screen]

Current Code:

```
  //Add the cells to collection
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: UsernameCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UsernameCollectionViewCell
    cell.usernameLabel.text = userNames [indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }

  //Upon Selecting an item
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if (indexPath.row == 0){
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("newUserSegue", sender: self)
    }
    else {
      sendData(userNames[indexPath.row])
      self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got it working! Here's how:

1. I added a button to the cell in the Storyboard.
2. Connected an outlet to the UICollectionViewCell class.
3. Edited view controller code to:

   ```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

     let cell: UsernameCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UsernameCollectionViewCell

     cell.usernameLabel.text = userNames [indexPath.row]

     cell.deleteButton?.layer.setValue(indexPath.row, forKey: "index")
     cell.deleteButton?.addTarget(self, action: "deleteUser:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

     // Remove the button from the first cell
     if (indexPath.row == 0){
       var close : UIButton = cell.viewWithTag(11) as! UIButton
       close.hidden = true
     }

     return cell
   }

   func deleteUser(sender:UIButton) {

     let i : Int = (sender.layer.valueForKey("index")) as! Int
     userNames.removeAtIndex(i)
     UserSelectCollection.reloadData()
   }
   ```

Many thanks to JigarM for his examples on GitHub:
https://github.com/JigarM/UICollectionView-Swift

Comment: What is `UserSelectCollection`?

Comment: `UserSelectCollection` is most likely his collection view outlet.

Comment: Hey I had added the addTarget method  but showing an error "Value of type 'UILabel' has no member 'addTarget'" any alternative way to do @Justin Lewis

Comment: Hello friends, Can you suggest me how to add delete button programming in collection view?

Answer (score 1):

Why not create custom UICollectionViewCell in IB and just add button to it ?
Register it to your collectionView with :

```
- registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:
```

You can use delegate or notification to process button tap.