# UICollectionView button

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create UICollectionView with buttons. I can set button titles but target action doesn't work. Below is my code:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TVButtonCell", for: indexPath) as! TVButtonCell
    cell.channelButton.setTitle(channelKeys[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
    cell.channelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FirstViewController.pressed(_:)), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
    return cell
}

    func pressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Button pressed")
}
```

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: does your app crash when you hit button? Can you past the complete stack trace?

Comment: I would recommend adding the IBActions in the UICollectionView cell and having delegates in the ViewController

Comment: Alternatively, maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610316/how-to-add-a-delete-button-to-collection-view-cell-in-swift?rq=1

Comment: Try using .touchupinside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn,
it's needed to add following func:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canFocusItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use delegates to call methods on viewcontrollers.

```
protocol TVButtonCellDelegate: class {
    func buttonClicked()
}
```

then create weak variable on TVButtonCell to pass delegate.

```
weak var delegate: TVButtonCellDelegate?
```

and also IBAction on tvbuttoncell to call method inside delegate

```
@IBAction func tvButtonClicked(sender: UIBUtton) {
   delegate?. buttonClicked()
}
```

then you simply apply delegate on firstviewcontroller

```
extension FirstViewController: TVButtonCellDelegate {
   func buttonClicked() {
       print("button clicked")
   }
}
```

and then assign firstcontroller to cell when you create one

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TVButtonCell", for: indexPath) as! TVButtonCell
    cell.channelButton.setTitle(channelKeys[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
```